Does Flickr’s Embed Feature Grant Permission for Commercial Use?
Flickr provides an "embed" feature that allows users to display photos on their websites by pasting a script, which loads content from Flickr's servers. Here’s how it works:

Authors agree to Flickr's TOS when uploading photos.
Users agree to Flickr’s TOS when using the site.
Flickr offers an embed script, but there’s no explicit mention in the TOS about licensing the photo for free use.
The embed script loads and displays the photo from Flickr's servers, without any direct file transfer.

Assuming I use the embed script on a site that generates commercial profit:

Who grants permission to use the photo in this context?
Am I actually using the photo directly, or just using the embed script provided by Flickr?
Who grants permission to use the embed script itself, and what are its limitations, especially regarding commercial use?

I'm particularly interested in understanding how Flickr’s TOS addresses permissions related to the embed feature, especially for commercial purposes.
Link: Flickr Terms of Service

I'll note that Sinclair v. Ziff Davis is probably relevant.  I tried to write up an answer citing that case, but wasn't able to find strong enough support in Flickr's terms to justify it.


Who grants permission to use the photo in this context?

Nobody. You either need to own the copyrights to the photo or obtain a separate license from the copyright holder (typically the photographer) to use the photo on your website.

Am I actually using the photo directly, or just using the embed script provided by Flickr?

You are using the photo. The technical details for how it comes to be shown as part of your site don't matter.

Who grants permission to use the embed script itself, and what are its limitations, especially regarding commercial use?

Assuming the script is a piece of computer code that you need to copy into your site (i.e., more involved than a HTML element containing a link), then the copyright of that code belongs to Flickr. They should give you a copyright license that gives you the right to use the script, but even if they don't do so explicitly, it can be inferred from the context that you should be allowed to create a verbatim copy if it into your site.

No
In fact, the ToS do not grant any user-to-user licence, so any use of third-party content requires permission from the third-party or an exemption from copyright like fair use.
So, the answers to your sub-questions are:

No one.
Yes, you are using the photo.
No one.

